# Programmatically styling layer after output is returned from QGIS 3 processing script?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

Hi this may be more of a python question rather than qgis processing script question. I've managed to successfully get the output that I want from my processing script, but I wish to take one step further and style it automatically with a saved qml file.

The code below doesn't work because the return ends my script. How should I go about doing this?

```
return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
iface.activeLayer().loadNamedStyle('Buffer.qml')
iface.activeLayer().triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the style after the processing tool (from Python) or are you trying to set the style from within the processing tool itself?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a subclass of QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface and apply the style in it's postProcessLayer method

First define the post processor class and create an an instance as follows

```
class LayerStyler(QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface):
    def postProcessLayer (self, layer, context, feedback):
        if layer.isValid():
            layer.loadNamedStyle('my_style.qml')

my_styler = LayerStyler()
```

Then set the post processor in processAlgorithm

```
def processAlgorithm():
    ...
    
    if context.willLoadLayerOnCompletion(dest_id):
        context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(dest_id).setPostProcessor(my_styler)
        
    return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
```